# Does CCA-security implies CPA-security

Tags: security-definition

While reading [Katz & Lindell's textbook (2nd edition)](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/imc.html) if found three main security definitions: ING-EAV-Security, ING-CPA-Security and ING-CCA-Security. (From this forum I know there are more, but these are the most basic ones). I also read, that ING-CPA-Security implies ING-EAV-Security and that ING-EAV-Security is weaker than ING-CPA-Security which is weaker than ING-CCA-Security.

**My question:** Does ING-CCA-Security also implie ING-CPA-Security?

Comment: Hint: How do the CCA definition(s) compare to the CPA ones, in particular the things an adversary can do?

Comment: I know what you mean: The CPA Experiment is included in the CCA experiment, therefore CCA should implie CPA, but because I couldn't find it in the book, I was/am unsure about it

Comment: In that case, could you perhaps find a proof yourself? That is, a reduction that if an adversary wins the CPA experiment against a scheme, it will also win the CCA one?

Answer (score 3):

My Sketch on the reduction proof:

1. Basic Assumption: I got a Cryptosystem #1 that is CCA secure
2. Based on this Cryptosystem I can build a CPA secure Cryptosystem #2, and I assume, that an adversary can break it with non negligible probability
3. Therefore I can build a Reduction: R can simulate the CPA game with A and just gives the messages of A to his challenger and the response back to A. R then outputs the result of A.
4. Because A has a non negligible probability in breaking #2, R also has a non negligible probability in breaking #1, which gives a contradiction to the basic assumption
5. Therefore CCA implies CPA

I hope the basic idea is correct.

Comment: And, a good exercise is to write it in a more formal way.